# Import Query String from AWS API Gateway into Lambda Python Function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, query-string

I am working on creating a Lambda Function which imports query string information into a database but I'm running into some trouble accessing the query string itself in my python code. I have setup the proper string variables within the API Gateway and also enabled Lambda Proxy integration from the Integration Request section.

Some articles and previous responses said I should be doing so by using:

`event["queryStringParameters"]['querystring1']`

I've setup a handler and I'm curious how to pass the request body into the function `my_handler`

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
import logging, traceback, os

#environment variables
ep = os.environ["EP"]
p = os.environ["PORT"]
du = os.environ["USER"]
pw = os.environ["PASSWORD"]
db = os.environ["DATABASE"]

#query string variables
def my_handler(event):
    servername = event["queryStringParameters"]["servername"]
    hostDesc = event["queryStringParameters"]["description"]
    hostRegion = event["queryStringParameters"]["region"]
    response = servername + hostDesc + hostRegion
    return { 
        'status code' : 200,
        'body' : json.dumps(response)
    }
```

Comment: The code that manipulates the event data needs to be inside a handler function: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html

Comment: Where is your lambda handler function that takes `event` as one of its arguments?

Comment: I've changed the query string variables section to instead pull from an event handler. It's listed in the code above. The problem I now face is getting the request body into the handler. I would think I could call this function and pass that somehow but I'm just finding links to the request library. This seems redundant if I'm already running the Lambda function with the JSON request body. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This was due to an error.

I was trying to pass a SQL query later in the script via a global string by attempting to use the handler results. What should be done is defining the query as a function and call it during the handler. Once the handler has the event variables from the body request, they can be passed into the function.

EX:

```
import logging, traceback, json

def query(hostServername, hostDesc, hostRegion):
    return "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE host ='"+hostIP+"' AND '"+hostPort+"' AND '"+hostServername+"'"

#query string variables
def my_handler(event):
    server = event["queryStringParameters"]["servername"]
    host = event["queryStringParameters"]["description"]
    region = event["queryStringParameters"]["region"]
    try:
        cnx = some_database_connect_function()
        cursor=cnx.cursor()

        try:
            cursor.execute(query(server, host, region))
            return{
            'Status Code' : 200
            }
        except:
            return log_err ("ERROR: Cannot execute cursor.\n{}".format(
                traceback.format_exc()) )

    except:
        return log_err("ERROR: Cannot connect to database from handler.\n{}".format(
            traceback.format_exc()))
```